Is it proper to capitalize the scientific method?
I am in the process of writing a book and I am making a lot of references to the scientific method. Is it appropriate (necessary) to capitalize references to the scientific method? As funny as that sounds, I literally don't know if that phrase needs capitalization or not. So, is it "the scientific method" or "The Scientific Method"?

Have a look at Google Scholar.

The vast majority of articles use lower case except in sentence-initial position, titles etc. Odd exceptions by respectable institutions (eg the University of Nevada) capitalise (as a veneration marker), but this feels archaic.

While this is not literally a look-up-in-a-dictionary question, it is something similar. Somebody who is writing a book on something, can be expected to be familiar with the literature in that field, and thus with how the relevant terms are used, spelled, and capitalised in that literature.

@jsw29 Obviously that's not the case. Read the room, son. Look at all the discussion on here, look at the upvotes. Does it look like there's a clear answer? A good question is always a good question and should never be closed.

The first two comments say the term should be lowercase. The answer with 3 upvotes says if the expression isn't in the title, it's lowercase. FumbleFingers in a comment argues that in Victorian times novel concepts were capitalized but we're in the 21st c.  LPH's link confirms it is lowercase, even if it contradicts with their analysis “you have the choice to capitalize this term or not”. For it to be a truly interesting question there must be some conflict, or some authority, maybe a style guide e.g.CMOS that says an author can chose whether to capitalise an expression or not.

If you can find an authoritative source that supports capitalising the name of a  methodology, quote it in the question and I'll be the first to cast a reopen vote. But so far... no one has cast a reopen vote, not even Fumble Fingers himself.

"Morons"? "Son"? Jeez. As far as I can tell your account has been open for ten years but has only four questions here and one answer (from 10 years ago). It might help explain others' actions to read the help pages and Meta section. If you feel the site's policies should be changed, the place to civilly discuss that is the Meta section.

A minimum requirement for a "good question" is that it shows a bit of research. This isn't just a hoop to jump through for no reason; if uncertainty remains after looking it up, it lets the question and answers address the sources, their validity, and how we should interpret them. For questions in the form "Can I do X?" it's a good idea to say why you think you might not be able to do X. I would never think of capitalizing "Scientific Method," and this question makes no explanation of why it should be capitalized.

And I just googled "define scientific method" and found this uncapitalized entry in five seconds.

@AndyBonner We removed the "research" close reason on this site because people were applying it far too broadly and arbitrarily. Nobody is harmed by this question being answered. Voting to reopen.

@alphabet the answer is in any dictionary, an online dictionary is easily accessible and citing an entry is a minimum requirement for this site. Unknown Coder can protest as much as he wants but the answer is easy, is there going to be third answer? Doubt it.  Now, if the OP wants to capitalise "Scientific Method" every time it appears in their book, that's his choice but he'll do better to explain to readers the reason for this choice. If he doesn't, there's a risk his words won't be taken seriously by sticklers for "grammar" or "punctuation” when it's really about style and convention.

It's not normally capitalized, but you'd get misleading results if you just searched case-sensitive Google NGrams for the scientific method, the Scientific Method, and The Scientific Method, because those three words often appear capitalized in titles. So here's the usage chart with of in the search strings...

There are almost no examples of all three words being capitalized, and my guess is that most of the matches for of the Scientific Method are actually "titles" such as Pioneers of the Scientific Method.
...and for completeness...


There's probably a historic work titled 'Of the Scientific Method':)

In Victorian times they often capitalized Important New Concepts, so the Atomic Theory used to be fairly common. But not today.

The Origin of Species (Evolutionary Theory) is probably still capitalised by some other than when used of the book,

@EdwinAshworth: The book was titled On the Origin of Species - but according to this usage chart, it was only "correctly" capitalized for a decade or two before publication (as I recall, he delayed publication to avoid upsetting his wife). But it looks like the power of the Internet (and the ease of Cut&Paste! :) has finally led to the book title being correctly transcribed in the last decade or two! Strange, that.

Great answer/use of NGram appropriately, but... you then voted to close? At least let others try.

@Mitch: Actually, I voted to close before i reconsidered and decided to post an answer. But I must have forgotten to cancel the vtc until some time later. Either that or the SO techies are getting really technical, and they've added code to automatically retract any vtc an answering user might have cast. I remember closevoting, but I don't remember explicitly retracting it. All I know is the system tells me I can't vote again because I voted to close and then retracted.

No, you didn't retract your closevote, it's still visible in the time stamp. On the other hand, I agree that the question was and still is off-topic. So I added my close vote.

@Mari-LouA: Odd. I'm sure when I posted my last comment 3 hours ago it said there was one closevote. Which I assumed was mine, so I tried unsuccessfully to retract it, but I just got "You cannot vote to close again after retracting your vote". But I would now question your "I agree that the question was and still is off-topic". Obviously I no longer think that, regardless of whether the system is accurately reflecting my votes here. Given that 6 people have upvoted the answer, I think you should respect the obvious majority opinion that this question is in fact On Topic.

You can appreciate and agree with an answer but still retain the question is off topic. The OP has five upvotes vs 3 downvotes, hardly a convincing majority. The question's been closed once, so it might or might not get closed a second time. Time will tell.

From what current usage shows, you have the choice to capitalize this term or not. It is a term that was not capitalized often in the past. This information can be extracted from the following Google page of results.
the scientific method

I see no reason to object to such use of capitalization. I am probably biased from exposure to German (where all nouns get capitals), and as a fan of Charlton Laird's "The Miracle of Language" I have a relaxed attitude towards grammar. Language is a tool for communication; if non-standard usage improves understanding, I'm for it. Writing about the Scientific Method gives an emphasis which may or may not be what you wish, but it ain't wrong.

I'd say two downvotes is harsh ... but who gets to decide whether something non-standard is going to improve understanding?

Grammar is not writing.
